# Access-VBA: How to reference a variable in Forms!frmA from Forms!frmB by its name?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Form `frmA` has a `Public` variable `rsExample As ADODB.Recordset`.

In `frmA`, I open another Form (`frmB`). For the sake of this question, let's assume that `frmName` and `rsName` in `frmB` are `String` variables:

```
frmName = "frmA"
rsName  = "rsExample"
```

When `frmB` did its job, I want to update `rsExample` and then close `frmB`.

I tried...

```
Forms(frmName).(rsName).MoveFirst
```

Didn't work, because Access is expecting a `Control`

**How can I reference the `Recordset` by `rsName`?**

**Update:**

In frmB...

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = CallByName(Forms(frmName), rsExample, vbGet)
rs.MoveFirst
```

Line 3 produces

> Runtime Error 91: object variable or width block not set

Thankful for hints

Comment: You want to use a value of one variable as a name of another variable? Try to use `Eval()` function.

Comment: If rsExample is recordset, bound to' frmA'  just refer to by`Forms(frmName).Recordset` Or to the public var with`CallByName(Forms(frmName), rsName, vbGet) `, but error indicates that`rsExample` is not set anymore (lost scope and gets nothing). Check with a watch on it at frmB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get class properties, you need to use `CallByName` (though, since class properties are defined at compile time, it's an antipattern and you really should not have the name in a variable).

```
CallByName(Forms(frmName), rsName, vbGet).MoveFirst
```

However, you should really think about ways to avoid needing to do this.

Comment: Thanks, Erik. frmB is serving to several forms, either simply to a textfield, or doing semi-complex operations on a listboxes recordset. Therefore, I pass the output-requirements in OpenArgs. Any hints on avoiding CallByName?

Comment: Create a generic function to either return the recordset, or do the operation, with a known name. I recommend not using `OpenArgs` too and replacing it with an `Initialize` function or sub to actually support types other than string, have separate arguments, and error if there are either unused parameters or missing required parameters.